# Run active job method in background or not depends on scenario

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job, rails-activejob

I am using active job to run my job in background.But i want to run one job in background in one scenario and run that job not in background in other scenario.Let me know how i can do that?

For example:

```
def update_name(user_id, name)
 user = User.find_by_id(user_id)
 user.update_attribute(:name, name)
end
handle_asynchronously :update_name, if is_delayed
```

In this example i am run update_name method in background if is_delayed is true.If is_delayed is false then update_name will not run in background.So is there anyway in active job to do this?

Comment: just define a `is_delayed` method within that class that would return a boolean value

Answer (score 3):

You can use `perform_now` or `perform_later` accordingly.

```
class UpdateUserNameJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(user_id, name)
    user = User.find_by_id(user_id)
    user.update_attribute(:name, name)
  end
end
```

Delay job execution based on `is_delay` value

```
if is_delayed
  UpdateUserNameJob.perform_later(user_id, name)
else
  UpdateUserNameJob.perform_now(user_id, name)
end
```

Comment: @AshikSalamn Can you tell me is perform_now run async or not?

Comment: `perform_now` will execute the job immediately without enqueuing.